# What happens when std::make_unique<T>() assigns to std::unique_ptr<T>?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have one doubt in std::unique_ptr.

When we assign std::make_unique() having no arguments, What will happen?

For example,

```
struct A {
  int a, b;
  A() {}
  A(int w, int e) : a(w), b(e) {}
};

int main() {
   A h(1, 2);
   std::unique_ptr<A> hello = std::make_unique<A>();
   std::cout << hello->a << std::endl;
}
```

In the above code, I mentioned default constructor, I got output for hello->a as a garbage value(random negative value)

But,
when I change the struct as below,

```
struct A {
  int a, b;
  A() {a=0;b=0;}
  A(int w, int e) : a(w), b(e) {}
};
```

The result value of hello->a as 0.

Why default constructor not assign the int as 0 when using std::make_unique()?

Answer (score 2):

The arguments passed to `std::make_unique<A>()` are the arguments passed to the corresponding constructor of `A`. Here you're not providing any, hence the default constructor of `A` will be called.

> Why default constructor not assign the int as 0 when using std::make_unique()?

Members of builtin type that are not initialized are left with an indeterminate value. This behavior is not related to either `std::unique_ptr` or `std::make_unique`; it is just how builtin types are default initialized.

Initialize them:

```
struct A {
  int a, b;
  A(): a(0), b(0) {}
  A(int w, int e) : a(w), b(e) {}
};
```

Comment: I would also emphasize that this behavior has nothing to do with `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @r3musn0x - Fixed